# AS3 Tweening a tint change

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this movieclip loaded on runtime called cHolder. I apply a tint at first, and when it is mouseOver there will be no tint. How do i apply a tween to make the change in tint appear more gradually? THanks!

```
        var imageLoader = new Loader();
        imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(projectDP));        
        var origColor: Color = new Color();
        origColor.setTint( 0x000000, 0.8 );
        cv.cHolder.transform.colorTransform = origColor;
        cv.cHolder.addChild(imageLoader);
        this.addChild(cv);


        cv.cHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onRoll);
        cv.cHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);
            function onRoll(e:Event):void
        {
            origColor.setTint( 0, 0 );
            e.currentTarget.transform.colorTransform = origColor;
        }           

            function onOut(e:Event):void
        {

            origColor.setTint( 0x000000, 0.8 );
            e.currentTarget.transform.colorTransform = origColor;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using a tween engine. You can use flash Tween, but I prefer to work with any of the many available engines out there, such as [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/).

to tween a tint you would do something like this:

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
TweenPlugin.activate([TintPlugin]);

var color:uint = 0x0;
var imageLoader = new Loader();
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(projectDP));        
    var origColor: Color = new Color();
    origColor.setTint( 0x000000, 0.8 );
    cv.cHolder.transform.colorTransform = origColor;
    cv.cHolder.addChild(imageLoader);
    this.addChild(cv);


    cv.cHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onRoll);
    cv.cHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);
        function onRoll(e:Event):void
    {
        //origColor.setTint( 0, 0 );
        //e.currentTarget.transform.colorTransform = origColor;
        TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget, 1, {tint:null});
    }           

        function onOut(e:Event):void
    {

        //origColor.setTint( 0x000000, 0.8 );
        //e.currentTarget.transform.colorTransform = origColor;
        TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget, 1, {tint:0x000000});          
    }
```

Comment: Thanks goliatone! I use the TintPlugin and ColorTransformPlugin from TweenLite.